# Javascript omdb api won't send all information

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

My problem is that I can only get 1 movie from each search. For example if I search "Harry potter" I want to be able to get all the harry potter movie JSON objects. At the moment I can just get Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows when searching for Harry potter.

```
$("#btnSearch").on("click", function(){
    var input = $("#search").val();
    $(".search-result").find("h3").show();
    $(".search-result").find("h3").text("Laddar...");
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+input+"&y=&plot=short&r=json",
        dataType: "JSON"
    }).done(function(data){
        var movie = data.Title;
        var year = data.Year;
        $(".search-result").find("h3").text(movie+"("+year+")");
        $(".search-result").find("h3").show();
    }).fail(function(data){
        $(".search-result").find("h3").text("Något gick fel...");
        $(".search-result").find("h3").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`OMDB Api` documentation](http://www.omdbapi.com/), you are performing a search `By Title` with `t` parameter.

You want to request `By Search` with the `s` parameter :

```
http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Harry+Potter&y=&plot=short&r=json
```

which gives you an array with all the matched data :

```
{
    "Search": [{
        "Title": "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2",
        "Year": "2011",
        "imdbID": "tt1201607",
        "Type": "movie",
        "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTY2MTk3MDQ1N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzI4NzA2NQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    }, {
        "Title": "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone",
        "Year": "2001",
        "imdbID": "tt0241527",
        "Type": "movie",
        "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjQ3NWNlNmQtMTE5ZS00MDdmLTlkZjUtZTBlM2UxMGFiMTU3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjUwNzk3NDc@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    }, 
    .......
    .......
    .......
    {
        "Title": "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix",
        "Year": "2007",
        "imdbID": "tt0944836",
        "Type": "game",
        "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BN2VhOGI0OTItZjVhMC00MThmLWI5YzEtYTk5ZTFhMjEzOGEzXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzg5OTk2OA@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    }],
    "totalResults": "77",
    "Response": "True"
}
```

You can use the following to get titles :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Harry+Potter&y=&plot=short&r=json",
    dataType: "JSON"
}).done(function(data) {
    var search = data.Search;
    for (movie in search) {
        console.log("title : " + search[movie].Title);
    }
}).fail(function(data) {
    console.log("fail");
});
```

Comment: Oh thanks, this is it! Could I ask a follow up question? Do I need to loop through all the JSON objects somehow? Surley I can't just use my current code  var 'movie = data.Title;'

Comment: Yes, I've included an example to list titles in ajax response